# to say + tara form

Tags: dialects, kansai-ben, grammar

I am a beginner of Japanese. Currently I've been studying for 1 month already and I am still n5. I try to watch Japanese TV as much as possible even though I don't understand what most of them say just so I can distinguish which words I do understand. I've also been doing some advance reading on certain topics like `"+tara"` form out of curiosity since I've been hearing that word a lot.

From what I researched, when you use the `tara` form, you change the verb into `plain past` form, like `aru` becomes `attara`. I guess my question is, why do people in TV say `iu tara` (as in 言う). Shouldn't it be `ittara` or `itte itara`? This question has been bothering me quite a lot like an itch I need to scratch. Any feedback is much appreciated! Thank you very much.

Comment: On a side note, I also noticed that many people in Tokyo (don't know about other dialects) read 言ったら as いうったら rather than いったら. I mean, despite making the pause corresponding to the small っ, the previous うsound is mildly audible as well.

Comment: ^ 「いうったら」じゃなくて 「ゆったら」って言ってるんじゃないですかね・・

Answer (score 8):

> 「言う」+「たら」

In Standard Japanese, the only correct combined form is:

> 「言ったら」

In Kansai dialects, however,

> 「言うたら」

is also used on a daily basis.  It is a regionally correct form.

Currently, many popular TV personalities in Japan are indeed from Kansai (including a number of most successful ones).  Thus, it is only natural that you frequently hear 「言うたら」 on TV.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I've been trying to figure that one but I couldn't find any answers on google.